# How add a value in a new column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have to consider values of two different column  of a dataframe. Calculate them  with a multiplication and then a division and put results in a new column. I write this, but it doesn't work:

```
for x in range(len(df1)):
    if df1.iloc[x,4] is not 'NaN':
            number1=float(df1.iloc[x,4])
            if df1.iloc[x,8] is not 'NaN':
                number2=float(df1.iloc[x,8])
                total=((number1*number2)/100)
                df1['total number']=total
df1.head()
```

this is my output:

```
   number1   number2      total number
0    400       90            100,0
1    35,5      50            100,0  
2    678       3,4           100,0
```

Instead, I would like this output:

```
   number1   number2      total number
0    400       90            40,5
1    35,5      50            17,75  
2    678       3,4           23,05
```

Comment: Can you add input?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand. You suggest to add result as an input?

Comment: Sorry, what means `but it doesn't work` ? Are in data some `NaN`? If yes, what is desired output?

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(number1=[400, 35.5, 678], number2=[90, 50, 3.4]))
df['total number'] = df.number1.mul(df.number2).div(100)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you need first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `,` to `.` and then cast to `float`:

```
df['total number'] = df.number1.str.replace(',','.').astype(float) * 
                     df.number2.str.replace(',','.').astype(float) / 100
print (df)
  number1 number2  total number
0     400      90       360.000
1    35,5      50        17.750
2     678     3,4        23.052
```

Also is possible use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) with [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df.number1 = df.number1.str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
df.number2 = df.number2.str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
print (df)
   number1  number2
0    400.0     90.0
1     35.5     50.0
2    678.0      3.4

df['total number'] = df.number1.mul(df.number2).div(100)
print (df)
   number1  number2  total number
0    400.0     90.0       360.000
1     35.5     50.0        17.750
2    678.0      3.4        23.052
```

If values in columns `number1` or `number2` contains some `NaN` is possible use parameter `fill_value`:

```
print (df)
  number1 number2
0     400      90
1    35,5      50
2     678     3,4
3     NaN     5.2

df.number1 = df.number1.str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
df.number2 = df.number2.str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
print (df)
   number1  number2
0    400.0     90.0
1     35.5     50.0
2    678.0      3.4
3      NaN      5.2

df['total number'] = df.number1.mul(df.number2, fill_value=1).div(100)
print (df)
   number1  number2  total number
0    400.0     90.0       360.000
1     35.5     50.0        17.750
2    678.0      3.4        23.052
3      NaN      5.2         0.052
```

---

```
df['total number'] = df.number1.mul(df.number2, fill_value=0).div(100)
print (df)
   number1  number2  total number
0    400.0     90.0       360.000
1     35.5     50.0        17.750
2    678.0      3.4        23.052
3      NaN      5.2         0.000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing simple math, you don't need any special functions. The calculations between columns will be vectorised by default:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(number1=[400, 35.5, 678], number2=[90, 50, 3.4]))
df['number3'] = df.number1 * df.number2 / 100
```

Output:

[image]